# How do I concatenate cell values and text together using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have a repetitive task I'd like to automate instead of using the =Concatenate function all the time. Here's my code so far:

```
Cells(2, 5).Value = Cells(2, 1).Value&" - "&Cells(2, 2).Value
```

Unfortunately this results in the "Compile error: Expected: end of statement" error, which highlights the " - ". How can I sandwich that text, " - ", between those two values?

Comment: You need spaces between your ampersand and the quotes, like this: `Cells(2, 5).Value = Cells(2, 1).Value & " - " & Cells(2, 2).Value`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Cells(2, 5).Value = Cells(2, 1).Value & " - " & Cells(2, 2).Value`

Answer (score 5):

@Joshua provided an answer for you situation.  Another solution that is more broad is one I've used before.  See the UDF copied here.

```
Option Explicit
Function ConcatenateRow(rowRange As Range, joinString As String) As String
    Dim x As Variant, temp As String

    temp = ""
    For Each x In rowRange
        temp = temp & x & joinString
    Next

    ConcatenateRow = Left(temp, Len(temp) - Len(joinString))
End Function
```

Then in your excel file, just use this formula, selecting the range of cells to join, and giving it a string (in this case " - ") to put in between them.

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion for whom need:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Dim x As String

i = 1
j = Range("max").Value
x = Cells(i, 2)

For i = 2 To j

x = x & " - " & Cells(i, 2)

Next i

'MsgBox (x)

Range("d1").Value = x

i = 0

End Sub
```